# Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation what happens if not logged in?

Tags: windows-store-apps

Seems like a simple/obvious question but I can't find the answer in the docs or anywhere else.  If I use this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.aspx

Mostly GetDisplayNameAsync, what happens if the user isn't logged in?  Do I need to use some other classes to handle login and add a some login/change account options to my UI?

All I need is the display name, for a leaderboard/high scores list.  I thought about using the Xbox Live API for leaderboards, but I guess that isn't open to the general public, so making my own.

Comment: Code can only run with a valid user account.  If no user is logged in then the only code that can run is in a service.  Which is configured to run with a specific user account, usually System.  Which is what you'll get back.

Comment: You always need a backup anyway since the user can opt-out of letting apps access this information.

Comment: Both good points, thanks.  If this will return the local system login name in some cases, that could be pretty random/weird or not something a person would want to be public (unlike a gaming screen name/login), is there something else I should be using better suited for this purpose? (perhaps I need to step back or ask another question)... I guess what I really want is the Xbox stuff, dangit.

Comment: Based on the 2 comments, it sounds like the answer is "it always returns something, unless blocked by privacy settings"?  If so, if either one of you want to post that answer so I can accept it and close this silly question, that would be great.  For my purposes I'm just not going to have a leaderboard/high scores, but maybe this will help a future reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments: It always returns something, unless blocked by privacy settings.

It's not very useful for my intended usage, since I was looking for more of a "screen name" or "gaming name" or "profile name".  Currently you would need to be a MS partner and use the XBox/Live SDK for that type of thing.